# Why isn't there a "departure" tag, the opposite of "arrival"?

Tags: discussion, tags, interesting-tags

We have an [arrival](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arrival) tag:

> Questions about activities, events and challenges close to the time at which you arrive in the country in which you will be expatriated.

What about a departure tag? I'm about to create one following a question of mine, but shouldn't it have existed already?

Comment: It might be useful for generic questions similar to the arrival tag. I don't think the site is big enough where we actually need to do tag cleanups and validate whether a tag is needed or not -> feel free to create it

Comment: I couldn't figure out the term https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/6268/is-there-a-term-for-when-you-are-no-longer-an-expat

Comment: @StrongBad: Well, I didn't necesarily mean when you stop being an expat - you could be leaving for another country that's not your own.